# Does the process automatically clean up the resources taken by pthreads upon exit

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

Assume that I have a code something like this :

```
void *my_thread(void *data)
{
    while (1) { }
}

void foo_init(struct my_resource *res)
{
    pthread_create(&res->tid, NULL, my_thread, res);

    /* Some init code */
}

void foo_exit(void)
{
    /* Some exit code */
}
```

The scenario is something like this. When the process gets initialized, the function `foo_init()` is called with a pointer to my allocated resources(the allocation is done automatically by some other function, which isn't under my control). Within the function I am creating a `pthread`, which runs in infinite loop.

After a while when the process is about to terminate, the function `foo_exit()` is called, but this time without the pointer to my resources, and hence I am unable to call `pthread_join()`, as my `tid` is contained within `my_resource` structure.

Now my question is that, whether the resources pertaining to the `pthreads` are destroyed upon the termination of the process by the OS or not? If yes, how can I make that sure.

Also is it safe to terminate the process without calling `pthread_join()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is preventing you from making the thread available for joining correctly (besides the poor exit strategy)?

Comment: @WhozCraig The code implementation is sort of a framework based. The functions foo_init() and foo_exit() are actually callback functions, and thus are not under my control.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about allocated memory, yes. When a process exits all virtual memory pages allocated to that process are returned to the system, which will clean up all memory allocated within your process.

Generally the OS is supposed to clean up all resources associated with a process on exit. It will handle closing file handles (which can include sockets and RPC mechanisms), wiping away the stack, and cleaning up kernel resources for the task.

Short answer, if the OS doesn't clean up after a process it is a bug in the OS. But none of us write buggy software right?

Comment: so is it safe to terminate the process without calling `pthread_join()`?

Comment: @raghav3276: Terminating a process inherently terminates all of its threads and does a lot of other things. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html for the consequences of process termination.

Comment: In one of the notes, it is mentioned that `Termination of a process does not directly terminate its children`, so does this also effect pthreads?

Comment: It is not inherently unsafe to ever terminate a process in any state (barring OS bugs). The thing to understand is that software is inherently buggy, so you should write code to behave properly. If it is truly just simple memory you'll most likely be fine either way, but other resources get tricky. Sockets and file handles could leak associated memory in drivers if the drivers have bugs. UI code could leak in the window manager process. There are lots of other cross-process resources that can leak.

Comment: Also, killing a process will kill all threads of the process, so any threads created with pthreads will get killed. That line in the document is referring to child processes. If you create sub-processes you'll need to propagate a signal to those processes to notify them to exit.

Answer (score 0):

All "regular" resources needed by a process are released automatically by the OS when the process terminates (e.g. memory, sockets, file handles). The most important exception is shared memory but also other resources can be problematic if they're managed not by OS but by other processes.

For example if your process talks to a daemon or to another process like a window manager and allocates resources, whether or not those are released in case the process terminates without releasing them depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question can be answered another way: pthreads do not own any resources, resources are owned by the process.  (A pthread may be the "custodian" of resources, such as memory it has malloc'ed, but it is not the owner.)  When the process terminates, any still running pthreads suddenly stop and then the usual process clean-up happens.

POSIX says (for `_Exit()`):

> • Threads terminated by a call to _Exit() or _exit() shall not invoke their cancellation cleanup handlers or per-thread data destructors.

For `exit()` POSIX specifies a little more clean-up -- in particular running all `atexit()` things and flushing streams and such -- before proceeding as if by `_Exit()`.  Note that this does not invoke any pthread cancellation cleanup for any pthread -- the system cannot tell what state any pthread is in, and cannot be sure of being able to `pthread_cancel()` all pthreads, so does the only thing it can do, which is to stop them all dead.

I can recommend the [Single UNIX® Specification (POSIX)](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/T101) -- like any standard, it's not an easy read, but worth getting to know.