# Check if the file still in use by another process before removing it (c, c++, linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, file

I need to remove a file (let's say it's named `<file.txt>`) when other process (it's from another program that I'm calling with `system("anotherProgram <file.txt>")` in my c++ code) finishes using it.

My program generates `<file.txt>`, passes it to an external application.
That application writes its steps into a log file and that application owner said that the file is not needed by application after some message (let's say `'aaa'`) is printed in the log file.

I suppose that external application just parses that `<file.txt>`and after finishing prints the message `'aaa'` in the log. So, I beleive after that, it should be safe to remove the `<file.txt>` in my code.

So, in my code I'm checking the log file and when I see the message `'aaa'`, I sleep my process for 1000 ms and then remove the file.

But in some cases I still get errors from that external application that it cannot find the `<file.txt>` file, so I guess even after the message `'aaa'` is printed in the log, the application still tries using the `<file.txt>`.

I'd like to know if there is something I'm doing wrong here.

PS: If I'd sleep for a longer time (say 10000ms), I'm not running into this issue.

Comment: Some operating systems, like Linux, can remove files even if they are in use.  (Assuming the file system being used allows that.  Using a foreign file system on Linux, like FAT32, might not be able to do that.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my program doesn't try to use (reopen) that file after deletion. It just generates that file, passes to a different program which reads it and writes 'aaa' into its log file as a sign that it's done with that file.

Comment: Well getting the `ENOENT` error (file not found) when trying to open a file is a normal error if the file doesn't exist (for example if it has been deleted). You need to be more specific, ***how*** is the `system` program "using" the file? What are you really doing?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, please see my edits in my previous comment.
My code doesn't use that file it just generates it and passes to other program (I don't have access to their codes). And as an indication that program doesn't need that file anymore I've been advised to check if the message 'aaa' appeared in the log.

Comment: "that application owner said that the file is not needed by application after some message". Then let *them* delete it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., depending on some conditions from my program, it's needed to delete that file or keep it. My program is kind of a wrapper over that external application.

Answer (score 0):

The sane way to do this, is to pass the file via a file descriptor, usually standard input.

(Most programs support reading their input from standard input, but if that particular one does not, you can still use `/proc/self/fd/N` for file descriptor `N`.)

Instead of using `system()`, you fork a child process, and have that execute the desired binary or shell command.  I have shown a suitable function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62910646/13893073).

In the parent process, you simply need to use the `/proc/self/fd/N` for the file name, and not close the file before the child has been executed.  You can unlink (remove) the file, as the underlying inode (the file metadata and contents) stay accessible for as long as at least one process has it open.

So, here is the scheme I would use:

1. Open and create the target file (using `O_CREAT | O_RDWR` or `O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR`, or if using stdio, `w` or `w+`).
2. If the file should be deleted when no longer needed, unlink it now.
3. Create the file contents.
4. If using stdio, we'll want to keep only the file descriptor, but close the stream:

   ```
   int fd = dup(fileno(handle));
   fclose(handle);
   ```

   Otherwise, we'll assume `fd` is the file descriptor to the target file.
5. Do `lseek(newfd, 0, SEEK_SET);` so the file position the description the descriptor refers to is at the beginning of the file.
6. Use a small buffer, say 32 chars, to print the path to the file descriptor (in the child process) to,via `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);`
7. Construct an array of strings corresponding to the program parameters, with [0] being the program name, [1] first parameter, and so on; with `(char *)0` as the final parameter.  Use the aforementioned `buffer` for the file name.
8. Call `pid = run(binary, argarray);`, where `argarray` is the aforementioned array of strings, and `binary` is the name of the binary to run (if in a directory named in `PATH`), or its full path.  (If it contains a slash, it is interpreted as an absolute or relative path; if not, the directories specified in PATH environment variable are used.)
9. If `pid == -1`, the command could not be executed; the reason is in `strerror(errno)`. Otherwise, the command is being run concurrently.
10. If you want to wait until the other program completes, call `reap(pid, NULL)`, or `reap(pid, &status)` if you want the details of its exit in `int status` (but remember to use `WIFEXITED(status)`, `WEXITSTATUS(status)`, etc., as described in [man 2 waitpid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Since the automagic deletion of the file is handled beforehand, if the parent process has nothing else to do afterwards, instead of forking a child process, you can simply replace the current process with the new process, by using only the `execv(binary, argarray)` or `execvp(binary, argarray)`, depending on whether `binary` is the path or only the name of the program binary/script to execute.